# Kafka topics not created empty

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster consisting on 3 servers all connected through Zookeeper. But when I delete a topic that has some information and create the topic again with the same name, the offset does not start from zero.

I tried restarting both Kafka and Zookeeper and deleting the topics directly from Zookeeper.

What I expect is to have a clean topic When I create it again.

Comment: It takes some time to delete a topic. Are you sure that it is deleted at the time you are re-creating it?

Comment: Have you tried physically deleting topic's directory from under Kafka `log.dirs` after deleting a topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A consumer was consuming from the topic and the topic was never actually deleted. I used this tool to have a GUI that allowed me to see the topics easily https://github.com/tchiotludo/kafkahq. Anyway, the consumers can be seen running this:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Comment: You also make sure "delete_topic_enable": true, in your kafka setting..however delete topic from admin tool doesn't effect from this setting.    As mentioned Giorgos Myrianthous  its take some time to delete topic